# Logut with retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to implement the logout for my app but I'm confusing. My response in postman is like this:
[image]

I did something like this:

```
private void logout() {
        UserRetriver logoutUsr = new UserRetriver();
        SharedPreferences editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCE, MODE_PRIVATE);
        String token = editor.getString("token", "");

        Logout log = new Logout();

        Callback<Logout> callback = new Callback<Logout>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Logout> call, Response<Logout> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCE, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.remove("token");
                    editor.clear();
                    editor.apply();
                    String success = log.getSuccess();
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                    System.out.println(success);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Logout> call, Throwable t) {
                progressBar.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        logoutUsr.logoutUser(callback, log, token);
    }
```

In the end I will destroy token, but is giving null value for success.

my retriever:

```
public void logoutUser(Callback<Logout> callback, Logout logout, String authorization) {
        Call<Logout> call = service.logout(logout, authorization);
        call.enqueue(callback);
    }
```

and my interface:

```
@POST("logout")
    Call<Logout> logout(@Body Logout logout, @Header("Authorization") String authorization);
```

and my model

```
public class Logout {

    @SerializedName("success")
    @Expose
    private String success;

    public String getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(String success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the problem i did not get that

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Cannot logout

Comment: What should happen when you try to log out?

Comment: It will give me the response from the server :
"success" : "logout successfully"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the end I will destroy token, but is giving null value for success.

You are trying to consume an object that it's empty, since you only created it doing

```
Logout log = new Logout();
```

But this object is empty, that's why you are seeing null when you do :

```
 String success = log.getSuccess();
```

### How to solve it?

What I'm seeing is that you are not using the response in any part of you method just asking if it's success

```
Callback<Logout> callback = new Callback<Logout>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Logout> call, Response<Logout> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCE, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.remove("token");
                    editor.clear();
                    editor.apply();
                    String success = log.getSuccess();
                    progressBar.dismiss();
                    System.out.println(success);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Logout> call, Throwable t) {
                progressBar.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
```

So I guess you want to do something like this :

```
 String success = response.getBody().getSuccess();
```

Instead of using `log.getSuccess()` since you are not doing something like :

```
log = response.getBody()
```